# Variable scope trouble, I think

Tags: javascript, node.js

I think I'm having trouble with variable scope. Ultimately I'm creating a text log containing certain files and their date last modified using this code:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFileSync('./scan_log.txt', "");

for(e in extensions){
    createScanLogHeader(extensions[e]);

    for (l in lines){
        if(lines[l].indexOf(extensions[e]) > -1){
        var fileMtime = getFileProperty(lines[l], "mtime");
        fs.appendFileSync('./scan_log.txt', fileMtime + " " + lines[l] + "\n");
        }
    }
}

function getFileProperty(path, prop){
    fs.stat(path, function(err, stats){
        return stats.prop;
    });
}
```

I get "undefined" prepended before the file path instead of the mtime file property. However if I put a `console.log(stats.prop)` in the `getFileProperty` function right above `return stat.prop` I do get the correct information logged to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `stat` call is asynchronous, and your `getFileProperty` function has no `return` value defined, so it returns `undefined`.

Either use `statSync` and return its value, or  pass a callback to `getFileProperty`.

```
    for (l in lines){
        if(lines[l].indexOf(extensions[e]) > -1){
            getFileProperty(lines[l], "mtime", function(path, prop) {
                fs.appendFileSync('./scan_log.txt', prop + " " + path + "\n");
            });
        }
    }
```

---

```
function getFileProperty(path, prop, fn){
    fs.stat(path, function(err, stats){
        fn(path, stats[prop])
    });
}
```

Comment: This works, but I have to hard code the `stats.mtime` property in `getFileProperty` for some reason. If I try to pass it `prop` it comes back undefined again.

Comment: @JasonBurgett: If you were trying to dynamcially name the property, then do `stats[prop]` instead of `stats.prop`.

Comment: That's it! I'm traditionally a Ruby programmer so once in a while I have a syntax mix-up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a scope problem, it's that you're doing `return stats.prop;` from the *callback* of `stat`. Since `stat` is async, the callback's return value has no meaning (and if it did, it would still be happeng later, asynchronous to the call to `getFileProperty`).

If you absolutely, positively must have `getFileProperty` *return* the value, then you have to use `statSync` instead. The `return` has to be from `getFileProperty`, not the callback you pass `stat`.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with the node.js framework, but a little googling shows that fs.stat(path,function) is asynchronous; so basically when you call

```
var fileMtime = getFileProperty(lines[l], "mtime");
```

you enter **getFileProperty** which *immediately returns*, and so the async return stats.prop basically goes nowhere...I *think* you should be using **fs.statSync(path)** insteaad, which is the synchronous version.